# append $_GET parameters to post

Tags: posts, get-posts, query-string, parameter

I try to find a plugin that can "auto insert" to post edit/add page a parameters by fill $get paramerts: for example:post.php?title=a&tags=ss,dds,aa
Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use functions that can do your job without a hassle that using $_GET will create? Use the action [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) to parse the $_GET array, and use the following functions with the parsed content.

1. [For inserting post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)
2. [For setting the post tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_tags)